# Bra ket notation in spherical coordinates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, coordinate-systems

A position eigenket can be written using a tensor product of individual Cartesian eigenkets as $\mathbf x=|x\rangle \otimes|y\rangle
\otimes |z\rangle$

Can I also using spherical coordinates write the same eigket as:

$\mathbf x=|r\rangle \otimes|\theta\rangle
\otimes |\phi\rangle$

with the individual components of tensor product satisfying :

$\left\langle\theta \mid \theta'\right\rangle=\ \delta\left(\theta-\theta' \right)$

$\langle\theta \mid \phi\rangle=0$

$\langle\theta \mid r\rangle=0$

And the completeness relationship :

$$\int(|\theta\rangle \otimes|\phi\rangle \otimes|r\rangle)\left(\langle\theta| \otimes\langle\phi| \otimes\left\langle r|\right) d V=1\right. $$

Comment: Yes, more or less. The one thing you gotta be careful about is the normalization. You want $\langle \theta | \theta \rangle = 1$ as you've written, but when you go over to coordinates and integrate over the delta function there's an extra factor that comes in (i.e. the integration is over $d(\cos(\theta))$, so you need a normalization in front of that delta function (I think).

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/691732/spherical-harmonics-and-bra-ket-notation?rq=1).

Comment: Close, but not quite. Indeed, $|\mathbf x\rangle=|x\rangle \otimes|y\rangle
\otimes |z\rangle= |r\rangle \otimes|\theta,  
 \phi\rangle$, but there are no meaningful  quantities such as $\langle\theta \mid \phi\rangle $. That is,  $|\theta,  
 \phi\rangle$ describes a sphere of arbitrary radius, and not two separate tensor factors.

Comment: @CosmasZachos, Thank you professor. If we've instead have a particle confined on a ring , won't the position eigenkets described by only one coordinate $|\theta\rangle$ ?

Comment: That is correct. A ring is a one-coordinate problem with a special topology.